# How to transfer emails from one Google Apps user account to another under the same domain?

Tags: google-workspace

Till recently when Google Apps Premier email had a maximum storage limit of 25 GB, my email **my.name@my-domain.com** got full, and I was forced to purchase and make another username for myself **name.my@my-domain.com**. Very recently Google has removed that restriction and now any amount of storage (upto 16 TB) purchased, will be shared across Google Drive, Google+ Photos, and now Gmail.

Therefore, due to inconvenience and expense occurring in maintaining two user accounts for a single person, I have decided to dump my second email and transfer all the emails (in Inbox, Archived, and in other labels) to be copied or moved to my first email, with label structure intact.

Drive is not an issue since the ownership of entire Drive content could easily be transferred through a very easy way [available in Google Admin Consol](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1247799). It is the email which is a real pain and about which Google seems to have not done or said something about.

Answer (score 3):

As of sometime in 2014 you can migrate emails using the Data Migration tool in the Admin console. This is meant for transferring data between domains, but you can use it to transfer data within your domain as well.

Before you start, you may want to log in as the source user and apply a label to all of their emails. Otherwise, they will just be thrown in the target inbox with just their existing labels, which can be hard to sort through. While you're there, grab an [application-specific password](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords) if you have two-step verification turned on.

1. Go to admin.google.com and sign in (you must be a domain administrator).
2. Go to Data Migration.[image: Data Migration icon]
3. Select "G Suite" for the migration source.
4. Enter the credentials for any user account on your domain. It is recommended you use the account that should receive a report of the migration. If you have 2-step verification in place, you will need to use an application-specific password.[image: options for setting up migration]
5. Select how much email to migrate, which folders to include/exclude, etc. The click Select Users. [image]
6. This will take you to the page for mass migration. Click the "Add" button in the lower right corner to start a new migration.[image: plus sign]
7. Enter the credentials for the target user account and select a source user. If you are using two-step verification, you will need to use an app-specific password for the source user.[image: user details]
8. Start the migration. It usually takes about 20 minutes to complete.
9. When you're done, if you need to migrate Contacts or Calendars as well, you will need to go to the menu in the top left and select "Exit Migration" before you can start a new migration.[image: menu - Exit Migration]

Comment: Good idea to add a label before starting the migration.

Answer (score 2):

Although it was not intended to be used this way, you can use Google Apps Migration for Microsoft® Exchange tool. Besides migrating from an Exchange Server, you can use it to migrate from an IMAP server. Google Apps provides IMAP access.

Here is the link to the tool and the instructions:

https://tools.google.com/dlpage/exchangemigration

Answer (score 1):

You can use any mail client program with IMAP protocol (ie. Thunderbird). Set up two accounts and transfer them (Drag & Drop) from one account to another. If you use Thunderbird messages will be **moved, not copied** to second account.